# Excel date/time calculation

Tags: excel, date, time, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two times that are given in this format:

`Fri 07/02/2014 10:16` with the cell using a custom format ddd dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

and display the result in hours.

I have two dates/times:

```
A1                    B1
Fri 07/02/2014 10:00  Fri 07/02/2014 10:42
```

The formula I have in C1 is

`=TEXT(TIME(LEFT(RIGHT(B1,5),2),RIGHT(RIGHT(B1,5),2),0)-TIME(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,5),2),RIGHT(RIGHT(A1,5),2),0),"h")`

Which gives me the answer 4, which I thought should be something like 0.68

Can anyone help?

Thanks

UPDATE:

A1 is actually in this format `07/02/2014  10:00:00`, which is then displayed as `Fri 07/02/2014 10:00`

B1 is entered as `'Fri 07/02/2014 10:42'` and displayed as `'Fri 07/02/2014 10:42'`

Comment: Yes, it gives a `#VALUE!` error

Comment: @pnuts Please see update. These values are being pasted in from another source, so I need to try and work with the pasted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=DATE(MID(B1,11,4),MID(B1,8,2),MID(B1,5,2))+(MID(B1,16,2)+RIGHT(B1,2)/60)/24-A1
```

and format the cell as [hh]:mm.

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to remove the day part from the string in B1, assuming that your default date format is dd/mm/yyyy then this should work in C1

`=MID(B1,5,16)-A1`

format C1 as [h]:mm

Answer (score -1):

Dates and time are just numeric values, integer part represent date (number of days since 1900-01-01) and fractional part represents time. So as he have 24 hours in a day, and if you have valid time values, independent of the format, hours can be calculated as:

```
= (B1-A1) * 24
```

Comment: Yeh, you right, I noticed it now :), but the important thing still remains, what I said is the relevant thing concerning dates, and it is information that most users dont know. If it is a string it is not a date and you cannot use any date or time function with it.