# Calculate Date times excel

Tags: excel

What I am trying to do to calculated the difference between to datetimes:

> 2016-12-24 00:00

and

> 2017-01-03 00:00

I have tried several "DateIf's" variations etc but nothing seams to get me the right result

My last approach to this issue was 
=MIN(B2-A2) but the reuslt was a bit of **12:51:45**

My expected output would be the right amount of time in between these tow dates posted above for example **240:00**

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626516/excel-date-time-calculation?rq=1 can help you

Comment: What output are your trying to get?

Comment: @CallumDA the right amount of hours, that should be the output

Comment: Just hours? Not minutes? Is that the problem?

Comment: @CallumDA the problem is to get the correct result

Comment: Quite frankly it is impossible to help you unless you update your question to show **exactly what the output should look like**. I can't read your mind. "Difference between x and y" can mean all sorts of different things. The difference between two dates can be expressed in many ways and you aren't making this easy for us to help

Comment: Is this literally just about formatting? You could try custom format [hh] (with the square brackets). NB - The value of the cell doesn't change, just the visible interpretation.

Comment: @CallumDA update my question

Comment: There are 10 days between your dates. Surely that should be 240, rather than 192?

Comment: @CallumDA stupid me sry for that I shall fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write this as your formula

```
=TEXT(A2-A1,"[h]:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time :)